# How to delete cached Android database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I had a database being loaded up at application startup. I made some changes to the DB, deleted the app from the emulator (wipe user data), and deleted it from my phone. Cleaned the project from the menu. However, when I run it, the old DB is still there. I am testing this notion by pulling the file in DDMS and opening it up in SQLite Explorer.

How can I remove this old cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database is located under
***/data/data/[apk-package-name]/databases/***

You can connect to the shell of the emulator and try to delete the databases inside this path

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse you can do the following, in addition to what Michele has proposed:

- Go to the DDMS page in eclipse
- Find the "file explorer" tab.
- Browse your way to /data/data/[Your App's Name]/databases/
- Select the database
- Delete

Also, each emulator will have its own database, so if you have set-up different emulators (for different screen densities for example), you would have to delete the database for each one of them.